# Rails3 'lable_tag' is not included by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed Rails 3, and I have some problems with `label_tag`. As I know `label_tag` method is included by default from `ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper`. But in my situation, it's not. Any suggestions?

`undefined method 'label_tag' for #<#<Class:0xb674433c>:0xb6743504>`

```
<%= form_tag :controller => "login", :action => "login", :method => "post" do %>
  <%= "<div class=\"notice\">#{flash[:notice]}</div>" if flash %>
  <%= label_tag 'login_name', t('login.login_name') %>
  <%= text_field_tag :login_name %>
  <%= label_tag 'password', t('login.password') %>
  <%= text_field_tag :password %>
  <%= submit_tag t('login.submit_button') %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has been edited to fix your spelling of "label", which kind of masks the likely fact that you've just messed up the spelling in your template.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?